# NullPointerException in my client of axis 2 web service with rampart security

Tags: eclipse, apache-axis, rampart

I've created axs 2 web service with rampart ws security  in eclipse (here s the tutorial I follow  [TUTORIAL](http://jkrzemie.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/ws.pdf) PAGE - 18-21

I've aplied the policy in service.xml by adding this code AND ENGAGED RAMPART MODULE

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="UTOverTransport"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:SignedSupportingTokens
                xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:UsernameToken
                        sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
            <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
                <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>axis2wstest.PWCBHandler</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
            </ramp:RampartConfig>

        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

Then I create web service client - here is the code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException {
          ConfigurationContext ctx;
          ctx = ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContextFromFileSystem("C:/Users/Tanya/workspace/testlnclient/WebContent/WEB-INF", null);
        TestlnStub stub = new TestlnStub(ctx);

        Testws cl = new Testws();
        cl.setX(5);
        ServiceClient client =  stub._getServiceClient(); 
        client.engageModule("rampart");    
        //client.addHeader(omSecurityElement);
        org.apache.axis2.client.Options o = client.getOptions();
        o.setPassword("pass");
        o.setUserName("test");
        TestwsResponse resp = stub.testws(cl);

        System.out.println("Response" + resp.get_return());


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

but it gives me an excetion

```
exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
    at axis2wstest.TestlnStub.testws(TestlnStub.java:191)
    at axis2wstest.testlnclient.main(testlnclient.java:35)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of `Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext` in the stack trace indicates that the `NullPointerException` is actually coming from the service and not thrown by the client. Check the server logs to see where the `NullPointerException` occurs.